# change value of input type="Button" from edit to save by using ClassName

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, javascript-objects

```js
function edit_row(element1) {
  var num = getId(element1);
  var favDrink = prompt("Enter input value");
  list[num] = favDrink;
}
```

```html
<input type='button' value='edit' class='edit-btn' onclick='edit_row(this);'>
```

when user click on this button **edit_row(this)** function will run. This will store value to the clicked index using prompt.

I have **dynamic array**, [the array will display like this in the table form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVUIm.png)
I want that, when user click on this button the value should also changed from edit to save. I want to do everything using **javascript**, not by jquery.

Comment: Post the tablet HTML

Comment: If you're using angular then replace 'value' with 'ng-value' and set it to a scope variable that holds your button text and change it within your onclick function

Comment: This doesn't look like angular

Comment: i have display function which contains html code this function is called in body tag with onload="display();"

Comment: `var html = "<table id='mytable' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>";
            for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) 
                {
                html+="<tr>";
                html+="<td>"+list[i]+"</td>";
                html+="<td id='btns'> <input type='button' value='edit' class='edit-btn' onclick='editrow(this);'>
                html+="</td>";
                html+="</tr>";
                }
            html+="</table>";
            document.getElementById("lists").innerHTML = html;`

Comment: https://drive.google.com/a/base29.com/file/d/0B1lSD7hOhXD6TW9XOWZzeGRZZTQ/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Add below lines to your `edit_row` function

```
if (element1.value === "edit") {
    element1.value = "save";
} else {
    element1.value = "edit";
}
```

This will toggle the text from `edit` to `save`, and vice versa.

https://jsfiddle.net/c9pet8uz/

Comment: can you look into my code, because it is still not working in my code

Comment: https://drive.google.com/a/base29.com/file/d/0B1lSD7hOhXD6dU5MMXdndzV4aXc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: you can go to chat and ask fir help there, comment section isn't an appropriate place for that. Also the file isn't publicly visible.

Comment: i don't have 20 reputation so i cannot talk in chat room

Comment: It won't work because you're asking for a prompt, so before the button gets re-rendered. The prompt pops up, and right when you submit in the prompt, you call the display() function again, and it resets everything.

Comment: Also it looks like a school project, but if it's anything other than a small school project. Please re-evaluate how you're writing this page, because it's very bad way of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the event on click of the button,

```
<input type='button' value='edit' class='edit-btn'onclick='edit_row(this, $event);'>
```

In the function, you can access the text value by `event.target.innerText`. Change it to whatever you want to.

```
function edit_row(element1, event) {
 event.target.innerText = 'Save'; // Change the text value to 'Save'
 var num = getId(element1);
 var favDrink = prompt("Enter input value");
 list[num] = favDrink;
}
```

Comment: Okay, then can you post bit more of your code snippet? I want to know what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/a/base29.com/file/d/0B1lSD7hOhXD6TW9XOWZzeGRZZTQ/view?usp=sharing